# angular-cli command to add 3rd party module into app module

Tags: angular-cli

Is there a way I can add a 3rd party angular module into my my main app module using angular cli command?

I have a angular module which is published to `npmjs` and available in public repository. So I installed it using `npm install --save @rep/module` and now I want to add that to my module using `angular-cli` command.

a angular cli command to do below thing

1. Add import statement in my `app.module.ts` like `import {SomeModule} from '@herd/angular-client';`
2. Add the imported module into `import block` like below

import code

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SomeModule,
  ]
});
```

I don't see any command like this. As I publish some of my module to be used in multiple project, it will be nice to have this command. also during jenkins deployment it will be helpful to deployment only production related modules.

also created a issue with angular-cli team as well. [command to add 3rd party module into app module](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9489)

Comment: Note that i have a situatio where I cannot go to the `app.module.ts` file add these these 2 lines as some automated tool like jenkins doing some stops if some module is required or not